# replacing words to "..."

Tags: functions

So, I have this post title that has a certain length (say 15 words).

When the browser width is reduced, the overflown words are placed to a next line by pushing everything down.

However, is there a way to replace the overflown words with "..." so that there is no pushing down on the other contents?

Thanks!

Comment: @steveKim you can also use CSS3: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a max-width on your element you could get around this with CSS like

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use css property text-overflow: ellipsis, but it works with one line only. If you want to reduce multiline text http://plugins.jquery.com/ellipsis/ will help you. (jQuery is always present in Wordpress)

Comment: Just remember, end users can disable jquery :-)